# How to re-render the value passed to Props in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, use-effect, react-props

I am implementing a bulletin board with React. I am implementing the comment function in the bulletin board as well, and I would like to receive a re-render of the content of the reply in the comment.

Here's the implementation:

In the PostView component, we get the content of the post and the comments of that post.
Pass the value of the retrieved comment list to the Reply component as props. (In the value passed, there is a comment array list of comments.)

When you leave a comment, it is rendered and new information is received, but the comment of the comment is not newly rendered. how do i solve it??

```
///PostView.tsx
function PostView({ match }: RouteComponentProps<MatchParams>) {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function CallPostData(id: string) {
      await axios.get(`/api/post/${id}`).then((res) => setdata(res.data));
    }
    async function CallComment(postId: string) {
      await axios.get(`/api/post/${postId}/comment`).then((res) => setPostCommentData(res.data));
    }

const replyList = PostCommentData?.map((item) => {
    return (
      <Reply
        key={item.commentId}
        commentId={item.commentId}
        userImage={item.userImage}
        userName={item.userName}
        comment={item.comment}
        commentTime={item.commentTime}
        commentList={item.commentList}
        MainPostId={postId}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

```
//Reply.tsx
export interface IReply {
  commentId: number;
  userName: string;
  userImage: string;
  comment: string;
  commentTime: string;
  MainPostId: string;
  commentList: IArray[];
}

function Reply(props: IReply) {
const Recomment = props.commentList.map((item) => {
    return (
      <li className="childReply_item" key={item.commentId}>
        <div className="comment_1">
          <Link to="" className="reply_thumb">
            <img
              src={
                item.userImage === null || item.userImage === "string"
                  ? "https://myrecord.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/7e1436db-68ea-45c5-b997-6de46f17280b.png"
                  : item.userImage
              }
            />
          </Link>
          <div className="reply_box">
            <Link to="" className="link_name">
              <span>{item.userName}</span>
            </Link>
            <p>{item.comment}</p>
            <p className="date">{item.commentTime}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

I need to refresh to get a new comment from a comment, but how can I get it without refreshing it?

[image]

I am attaching a picture for your understanding.

I want to render comments in the comments below when registering.

Comment: Code above is not enough to understand the workflow. only a replay and loop of recommenting is there. how are you adding a new comment and comment from comment?

Comment: @sojin Please see the post again.